# How to reuse the table component in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Iam new to Angular2 framework. Iam trying to reuse a single table component throughout my application. when, iam trying to do it ,iam facing difficulties to repeat any kind of array in my table row . How can i make my table row to iterate any kind of array which is passed as input to my table component.

Is it possible to reuse my table component when i pass array as an input to it??

Following is my code snippet. How can i reuse it? Please suggest me the best approach to be done.

app.component.html

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <td>name</td>
     <td>empid</td>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of items;">
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.empid}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  items=[{name:"ravi",empid:"10215"},{name:"ravi",empid:"10215"},{name:"ravi",empid:"10215"},{name:"ravi",empid:"10215"},{name:"ravi",empid:"10215"}];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrays of types with different structures, you *could* just create a pipe and extract the values (though this does add about half more of a memory footprint)

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'objectValues'
})
export class ObjectValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(obj: any) {
    let result = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Here we are just extracting the values from the object, and returning them in an array.

Then in your table, just do

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-table',
  template: `
  <table>
   <thead>
     <td *ngFor="let header of headers">{{ header }}</td>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
       <td *ngFor="let value of item | objectValues">
         {{ value }}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
  `
})
export class TableComponent {
  @Input() items
  @Input() headers
}
```

#### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ywL1QGCI0hGQnVqoWGFE?p=preview)

**See also**

- [iterate maps with ng-for](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2246) for discussion on iterating maps and objects in `ngFor`. It is not currently supported, so others have proposed work-arounds.

Comment: Thank you very much @peeskillet. I was very impressed with your answer

Answer (score 2):

yes you can make your tables as reusable table component:

**table.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent {
  @Input() items;
  @Input() field1;
  @Input() field2;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

**table.component.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <td>name</td>
  <td>empid</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <td>{{item[field1]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[field2]}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-table [items]="data" [field1]="field1" [field2]="field2"></app-table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

    export class AppComponent{
           // data: any[] = [{name: "ravi", empid: "10215"}, {name: "ravi", empid: "10215"}];
  // field1: string = 'name';
  // field2: string = 'empid';

  field1: string = 'product';
  field2: string = 'price';
  data = [
    {product: "mobile", price: "10215"},
    {product: "camera", price: "10215"}
  ];



      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinay Pandya i got your answer. Iam facing difficulty to repeat the array (data) when its object property changes ie. if 
data = [{product: "mobile", price: "10215"}, {product: "camera", price: "10215"}]; how can i repeat them. ?? Please help me.

Comment: see my updated answer, you need to send object key name as @Input() and that's it. try product array and employee array in AppComponent class, also dont forget to change field name as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Vinay Pandy will refer to it. Is it possible to iterate it using key value ??

Comment: Iam accepting your answer. Thanks for your answer. If you got any other efficient answer please let me know.

Comment: anytime, right now this is working, in future if angular 2 change something than it will change, at that time we will see.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.keys = Object.keys(this.data);

<tr *ngFor="let row of data">
  <td *ngFor="let key of keys">
       {{ row[key] }}
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks @GoNode5 i like your simplest way of approach.